# Python Tkinter Error (Weather API)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have this program which uses a Weather API and gets the weather of a city.
The city is read from a text file.

Here's the Python File:

```
import urllib2
import json
from string import capitalize
import Tkinter as tk

city = ''
data = open('data.txt', 'r+')

for i in data:
    if 'current_city' in i:
        index = len(i)
        city = i[13:index]

print city

def kelvinToCelsius(kelvin_temp):
    return str(int(kelvin_temp)-273) + ' Degree Celsius'

def setText(string, string_var):
    string_var.set(string)

def getCurrentTemperature(city):
    city = city.replace(' ', '%20')
    url_to_call = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_call)
    json_obj = json.load(response)
    print url_to_call

    current_desc = capitalize(json_obj['weather'][0]['description'])
    current_temp = kelvinToCelsius(json_obj['main']['temp'])


    setText(city, city_name_label_text_var)

    return current_desc + ': ' + current_temp

maingui = tk.Tk()

city_temp_and_desc_label_text_var = tk.StringVar()
city_name_label_text_var = tk.StringVar()

main_frame = tk.Frame(maingui, width=500, height=200, borderwidth=2)
main_frame.pack()

city_name_label = tk.Label(main_frame, textvariable=city_name_label_text_var, font=12).place(x=226, y=0)
city_temp_and_desc_label = tk.Label(main_frame, textvariable=city_temp_and_desc_label_text_var, font=30).place(x=140, y=99)

setText(getCurrentTemperature(city), city_temp_and_desc_label_text_var)

tk.mainloop()
```

Please help! I learned from the error that the problem is that the city name is not read from the text file properly and is equal to '' when it is passed to the url.

I tried many different ways to avoid this error but none of them worked.

EDIT: I forgot to mention but an initial program writes the text to the text file and then runs the above python script. I also forgot to mention this but when the above file is run directly, it works. But when I checked the rerouting python script writes properly to the text file.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anand\Coding\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\WorkBench\The Weather\src\__main__.py", line 54, in <module>
    setText(getCurrentTemperature(city), city_temp_and_desc_label_text_var)
  File "D:\Anand\Coding\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\WorkBench\The Weather\src\__main__.py", line 35, in getCurrentTemperature
    current_desc = capitalize(json_obj['weather'][0]['description'])
KeyError: 'weather'
```

Comment: please add the error message to your question

Comment: You may want to check if you actually opened the file and that data.txt is in the directory you expect it to be. Use "r" instead of "r+" if you are only going to read the file.

Comment: Thanks @imran. Your comment got me thinking about the text file and it didn't take many seconds before I realised that I didn't close the text file after writing to it in the rerouting program. I'll try this out and I'll also change the 'r+' to 'r' as per your comment.